# FATAL ERROR: main - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run code copied and pasted from a book. All the code is correct.. I have tried other examples and everything keeps crashing in the emulator. Nothing will work! What might cause these errors besides the XML? It is just a solar system program with 4 classes. No errors appear until it is done installing, and when it tries to launch the program, I get the fatal main error. What could be going on here?? I am using a Nexus One emulator 4.4.

Comment: Can you copy paste the crash from the logs?

Comment: Android Java?  Or desktop Java?  You do know that Android does not have a `main()` method?

Comment: @Simon - I believe the reference is to the main thread.  At any rate, this is in fact a common Android runtime error message, typically caused by the program crashing during the creation of an Activity.

Comment: Reading the log will tell you what code is causing the crash ("Caused by" ...). Please post the relevant code portion, which will help us help you ;)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sure, but I've seen many people make that mistake - copy/paste some code and end up with `public class SomeThing{ public void main(){}}`

Comment: Here is the logcat:                                                02-25 11:35:08.980: D/dalvikvm(1120): newInstance failed: Lcom/example/bouncycircle/Square; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
02-25 11:35:08.990: D/AndroidRuntime(1120): Shutting down VM
02-25 11:35:08.990: W/dalvikvm(1120): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ac1ba8)
02-25 11:35:08.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main